# Zend Navigation Menu customising to use JQuery jdmenu

Tags: jquery, zend-framework, uinavigationcontroller

So i've followed the tutorial [Zend Framework: Navigation and Breadcrumbs with an XML File in ZF 1.8](http://blog.ekini.net/2009/06/10/zend-framework-navigation-and-breadcrumbs-with-an-xml-file-in-zf-18/) and all is working well, but i now want to use the [jdmenu](http://jdsharp.us/jQuery/plugins/jdMenu/) jquery plugin to renderer a cleaner looking horizontal menu. By default, the Zend framework wraps the menu html code in this element name

```
<ul class="navigation">
```

I think i can call this method to set the 'ul' element class atttribute to 'jbmenu'

```
Zend_View_Helper_Navigation_Menu->setUIClass('jdMenu');
```

but i'm not sure how i can get access to the Zend_View_Helper_Navigation_Menu object reference. Should this be done in the Bootstrap.php file in the __initNav() method?. Any advise would be appreciated.

Comment: Even with the jd_menu plugin loading, the structure of the zend generated menu html is not as i'd like, and it doesn't meet the expectation of the jd_menu library. For the moment, i'm going to park this, and just use a custom css solution in my application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to specify this in Zend you access the View Helper when printing the menu in your layout. So you could use:

```
//layout.phtml
echo $this->navigation()->menu()->setUlClass('jdMenu');
```

Comment: thanks for that - the correct css class name is 'jd_menu'.

<?php echo $this->navigation()->menu()->setUlClass('jd_menu'); ?>

Comment: Even with the jd_menu plugin loading, the structure of the zend generated menu html is not as i'd like, and it doesn't meet the expectation of the jd_menu library. For the moment, i'm going to park this, and just use a custom css solution in my application.

Answer (score 1):

jdmenu initializes like this:

```
$('ul.jd_menu').jdMenu();
```

So, you should be able to leave Zend alone and simply alter the initialization line to match the name of the UL being used. E.g.,:

```
$('ul.navigation').jdMenu();
```

Comment: I couldn't get the jdMenu() javascript call to work, so i was just using jquery to add the extra class name to the zend generated div.

$("ul.navigation").addClass("jd_menu");

Answer (score 0):

Use  this:

$this->navigation()->menu()->setUlClass('jd_menu')->renderMenu($container);